# Replacing urls with embed code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, embed

I am writing a javascript function to replace urls with embed code (eg. youtube urls with a youtube video). I'm thinking of using String.replace() with the following callback:

```
 function replacer(match) {
    if (isYoutubeLink()) {
       return getYoutubeEmbedCode();
    }
    // repeat for other types of urls
 }
```

However, since getYoutubeEmbedCode() makes an oembed api call, it is asynchronous and cannot return a value. How would I go about replacing all the urls?

EDIT: I would also need to create a new node after the urls have been replaced with code so that the videos show up as actually videos and not just as html text. I think this means I would also need to know when all the async tasks have finished.

Comment: You want to also support platforms other than youtube, right?

Comment: Yes there can be an arbitrary number of platforms

Comment: How do you call `replace()`? Specifically, what is the regex you're using for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

you should hook into onreadystatechange of your asynchronous request

```
request.open("GET", youtubeurl, true);
request.onreadystatechange = getYoutubeEmbedCode;
request.send(null);
```

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/76dJh/

Comment: Eh... that's not his problem. His problem is that `String.prototype.replace` is only designed for sync callbacks.

Comment: he should not put asynchrouns request in replace() but replace in function called after request ends...

Comment: also he clearly stated that he is THINKING about putting that logic into replace() - and what user put in edit is also a reason to go according to my answer as he can be sure that all data is there already to working with...

Comment: @shoopdelang please check my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Pass it a closure that will handle it when you're done.

```
function replacer(match) {

    if (isYoutubeLink()) {
       getYoutubeEmbedCode(function(){//code to change URLs here});
    }
    // repeat for other types of urls
}
```

I would not structure my code exactly like this, I would abstract that closure to a variable that is visible to the scope of the call but this is for succinctness.

--Edit--

After more though I realize that this is not the approach you want to use at all. You're looking to replace the links (anchor tags) themselves, not the href attributes on them.

1) Select all of the anchor tags you expect to change into youtube videos and store them in an array. This is easy if you give them all a class or data-attribute (I prefer data-attribute in this case since it makes comparison easier and less likely to collide with basic css classes).

2) Loop through them, and compare their href values or their data-attribute names (<--that's the advantage of using data-attribute) to decide which youtube vid to pull on a per-element basis. Pass the ajax call a callback function (a closure as I mentioned in my original post) that is passed the target anchor tag.

3) Use the target anchor tag when the ajax comes back to place the youtube code after it (using append or something of the sort).

4) remove the target anchor tag.

5) now that you want to add something after the video, since you have the video here, you can do it now by targeting it.

All done.

This is a better approach in my opinion. Maybe I am missing the point of your post but from what I read it sounds to me like your approach is trying to do something other than what you really want to do.

Comment: Why downvote? This isn't a bad solution. He just modifies the code in getYoutueEmbedCode to call the passed closure.... I wish people would state WHY they downvote.

Comment: So how exactly can he return the result from `replacer`?

Comment: The question is "how can I change the URLs"- you dont need to return a result from replacer. Pass a closure, and the closure handles updating the URLs. A perfectly (and widely used) viable solution. If you agree with that please remove your downvote because I strongly disagree with it.

Comment: @dudewad: RTFM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @thejh Read my answer more thoroughly- I am suggesting an alternate approach here. Am I mistaken that "match" is the value he's looking for here?

Comment: So how exactly would the string replacing work with your approach?

Comment: How would you actually change the url in the closure?

Comment: It depends on what the OP is replacing. Are we replacing href value of the anchor tag (which makes no sense since we're trying to replace links with youtube videos)? And if that's the case, I would approach this in a completely different way. I'll add some code to the closure so you can see what I mean, though. (dunno if the youtube code actually changes a link into a video, so this might just be the solution)

Comment: @thejh My bad- I'm realizing now that the approach of using string replace is actually not even what the OP wants to do. Changing now

Comment: Unfortunately my links aren't in <a> tags. They are just plain text.

Comment: Why dont you wrap them in spans if you don't have the option of changing them to links? That will make them target-able

Comment: And if the case is that you're literally doing str.replace on the document itself directly, then you should definitely be getting the youtube data BEFORE starting, it'll save you all of the headache.

Comment: How am I supposed to wrap a span tag around the link? This is a text node so if I add <span> it will show up as the text "<span>"

Comment: Right. Don't use the replace method here. Use javascript to select all of the spans you've placed by class name:
<span class='replaceMe'>www.example.com</span>
And follow the steps above. It is better in this case to create and remove dom elements rather than editing text in the dom- you are actually adding embedded youtube videos, and it's bad practice to slap html as text onto the document. Using jquery to do the selecting, adding, and removing of the objects will be easier (because you're guaranteed cross-browser compatibility) but it's not required, obviously.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to write your own string replacer, I'm afraid. Maybe something like this:

```
function replace_async(str, pattern, replacer, cb) {
  var result = '';
  function _(arg) {
    result += arg;
    var first_match = pattern.exec(str);
    if (!first_match) {
      result += str;
      return cb(str);
    }
    result += str.substr(0, first_match.index);
    str = str.substr(first_match.index+first_match.input.length);
    replacer(first_match, _);
  }
  _('');
}
```

Then you can write async replace callbacks like this:

```
replace_async("foo bar http://youtube.com/... baz http://youtube.com", url_pattern, function(match, cb) {
  getYoutubeEmbedCode(match.input, cb);
}, function(result) {
  alert("Text with translated URLs:\n"+result);
});
```

Of course, you could also just do a synchronous request as a workaround, but that'd not really be a good idea.

Comment: Oh, I'm getting downvotes, too? Explain the downvote, please :)

Comment: you put cannons to mosquito - all he needs is to call his function after request ends 1. get urls 2. for each url call request 3. on request end replace content of url with returned code - no mambo-jumbo in the middle

Comment: @Ochi: Well, and HOW would he go about replacing it? You need to consider that all callbacks for completed http requests would have to operate on the same string, track location changes of the matches because the embed codes are longer than the original text, ...